# Complex limit in the definition of differentiability

Tags: complex-analysis

Using the Cauchy-Riemann equations it is easy to see that i.e $f(x+iy)=y^2$ is complex differentiable for all $x\in\mathbb R$. However, I'm struggling a bit to verify this just by the definition.

So let's take some $x\in\mathbb R$, and let $h=a+ib$. Then $$\left|\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\right|=\left|\frac{b^2}{a+ib}\right|=\frac{a^2}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}},$$but how do I handle the limit as $a+ib\to 0$? If I approach from the real axis, meaning $b=0$, then the limit is $1$. But if I approach on the line $\{x+ix|x\in\mathbb R\}$ the limit is $\frac{1}{ 2}$. Is there an error in my thoughts? How do I make sense of this?

Comment: There's an error in  your calculation: $|a+ib|\ne a^2+b^2$.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I edited it. My question remains the same though.

Comment: With the revised version "But if I approach on the line $\{x+ix|x\in\mathbb R\}$ the limit is $\frac{1}{2}$" is wrong.

Comment: Yes, so the limit in both of my examples is $0$ which starts to make more sense. However, how can I argue properly that it will always be $0$ no matter where I approach from?

Comment: Since we just got the algebra straight a minute ago maybe we should think about it a little. Ok, $a^2/\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\le a^2/\sqrt{a^2}=|a|\le|a+ib|.$

Comment: $\left|\frac{b^2}{a+ib}\right|=\frac{b^2}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$, not the one you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$
\left|\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}-0\right|=\left|\frac{{b^2}}{a+ib}\right|=\frac{\color{red}{b^2}}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}
$$

Now, you want to show that
$$
\lim_{(a,b)\to(0,0)}\frac{b^2}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}=0,
$$

which is essentially multivariable calculus. Observe that for $b\neq 0$,
$$
0\leq\frac{b^2}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\leq \frac{b^2}{\sqrt{b^2}}=|b|.
$$

Comment: got it, thanks!